# Issues parsing grok pattern for nginx error log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Hello to all I have the following line in the a log file

```
2018/05/11 23:08:28 [error] 53734#53734: *621532077 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.22.10, server: www.testserver.pt, request: "GET /methods/userinfo.ashx/getUserOpenBetsData? HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://188.11.2.3:443/methods/userinfo.ashx/getUserOpenBetsData?", host: "www.testserver.pt", referrer: "https://www.testserver.pt/"
```

And I am trying to use the following grok pathern to parse it

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
 filter {
        grok{
        match => {"message" => '%{F_TIMESTAMP: timestamp} \[%{DATA:Message_type}\] %{DATA:EventId}\: \*%{NUMBER:Secondaryid} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}, client: %{IP:origin}, server: %{URIHOST:domain}, request: "%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}", upstream: %{QS:userRequest}, host: "%{URIHOST:host}", referrer: %{QS:referrer}'}
        }
        date{
        locale => "en"
        match => ["timestamp", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]
        target => "@timestamp"
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd.HH}"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
```

Is not doing the trick.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be really helpful if you can add more details in your question, like, what kind of error you are getting, and what type of log it is? etc. In your case its NGINX log and I have posted this answer. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search reveals its `NGINX` log,

You can use following grok pattern,

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}, client: %{IP:client}, server: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request: %{GREEDYDATA:request}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2018/05/11 23:08:28"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2018"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "05"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "11"
    ]
  ],
  "TIME": [
    [
      "23:08:28"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "23"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "08"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "28"
    ]
  ],
  "severity": [
    [
      "error"
    ]
  ],
  "pid": [
    [
      "53734"
    ]
  ],
  "threadid": [
    [
      "53734"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "53734",
      "621532077"
    ]
  ],
  "connectionid": [
    [
      "621532077"
    ]
  ],
  "errormessage": [
    [
      "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream"
    ]
  ],
  "client": [
    [
      "192.168.22.10"
    ]
  ],
  "IPV6": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "IPV4": [
    [
      "192.168.22.10"
    ]
  ],
  "server": [
    [
      "www.testserver.pt"
    ]
  ],
  "request": [
    [
      ""GET /methods/userinfo.ashx/getUserOpenBetsData? HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://188.11.2.3:443/methods/userinfo.ashx/getUserOpenBetsData?", host: "www.testserver.pt", referrer: "https://www.testserver.pt/""
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can [test it here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Please also look at the following [example for parsing nginx error log](https://github.com/rooprob/logstash-various/blob/master/logstash-nginx-error.conf)
on github.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice!!
Thanks, your info was very helpful
Still having some issues configuring multiple pipelines but for the most part I now have this configuration file finished

Comment: @ricardogaspar, glad i helped, please feel free to post other question for different issue and someone will try to help.